# dynamic markers on google maps on flutter application

Tags: php, android, mysql, flutter

stack overflow in my MySQL DB I have location data which I want to display on google map in the form of markers. like I have lat lng name of place etc. any idea how to implement this kind of functionality. My app requirement is client add different locations on maps through form I am using PHP web services to get data from DB in JSON format. the form is used to put data in DB like lat lng name of place etc any help regarding this particular functionality is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google Maps for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter):

```
GoogleMap(
 markers: put_your_markers_set_here
)
```

Comment: I want to fetch from json array